# C# Timer Start and Stop

Tags: c#

I did a button, and when u click on the button, it will start the `Timer1.Start();`

And when u click again on the same button, it will stop the `Timer1.Stop();`

I tried

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

And the code above is not working, i get always error.

So if i click on the button, timer will run, if i click again on the same button, timer will stop.

Comment: timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled.  Do practice using the if-statement.

Comment: And what error did you get? It probably tells you that you can't just have an else without an if

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/if_else_statement_in_csharp.htm

Comment: @HansKeﬆing But what do i write on if, because all i got is button.

Comment: You need to use the if to check the current status of the timer, so you can decide what action to take

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleTimer();
    }

private void ToggleTimer()
    {
        !timer1.Enabled ? timer1.Start() : timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
    }
```

ToggleTimer() will first check whether the timer has been disabled, and if so, it will either start the timer and mark it as enabled, or stop it and mark it as disabled.

Comment: You will need to switch things around some: you start and disable the timer, or stop and enable

Comment: Thanks, wrote that too quickly. Of course, you’re right! Already edited my answer